# How to use TPUEstimator.export_saved_model with Tensorflow 1.12?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tpu

`export_saved_model` used on TPUEstimator raises TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor with Tensorflow 1.12.0. Am I using it incorrectly or if it is a bug is there some workaround?

I would like to train a model on TPU using TPUEstimator and then use the trained model locally on CPU. I cannot use the graph saved during training directly, but I need to use `export_saved_model` instead ([Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25488)).

`export_saved_model` on TPUEstimator works correctly with Tensorflow 1.13.0rc0, however it fails with current Tensorflow 1.12.0 ([another Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25652)). At the moment, however, TPUs with Tensorflow 1.13 are not available at Google Cloud and TPUs with Tensorflow 1.12 are not compatible, so upgrading Tensorflow to 1.13 is not an option.

The relevant code is:

```py
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    feature = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, 2])

    return tf.estimator.export.TensorServingInputReceiver(feature, feature)

estimator.export_saved_model(FLAGS.export_dir, serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

**Expected result.**
The model should be exported correctly. This happens with Tensorflow 1.13.0rc0 or with TPUEstimator replaced with Estimator. The former can be reproduced using [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bzpxlevnmDriBUrg3RihxXGOI4pmtYQQ)).

**Actual result.**
Exporting fails with TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  and the traceback included below. This can be reproduced with [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FEvd47JRZtAJZcwB10gqKDhSCWx_cRCW).

```
...
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py:1044: calling SavedModelBuilder.add_meta_graph_and_variables (from tensorflow.python.saved_model.builder_impl) with legacy_init_op is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Pass your op to the equivalent parameter main_op instead.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets added to graph.
INFO:tensorflow:No assets to write.
WARNING:tensorflow:rewrite_for_inference (from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu.tpu) is experimental and may change or be removed at any time, and without warning.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Running infer on CPU
ERROR:tensorflow:Operation of type Placeholder (policy_labels) is not supported on the TPU. Execution will fail if this op is used in the graph. 
ERROR:tensorflow:Operation of type Placeholder (sat_labels) is not supported on the TPU. Execution will fail if this op is used in the graph. 
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 527, in make_tensor_proto
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 527, in <listcomp>
    str_values = [compat.as_bytes(x) for x in proto_values]
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 61, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got dict_values([<tf.Tensor 'sat_prob:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'policy_prob:0' shape=(?, ?, 2) dtype=float32>])

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neurosat_tpu.py", line 253, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "neurosat_tpu.py", line 248, in main
    estimator.export_saved_model(FLAGS.export_dir, serving_input_receiver_fn)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 734, in export_saved_model
    strip_default_attrs=True)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 663, in export_savedmodel
    mode=model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 789, in _export_saved_model_for_mode
    strip_default_attrs=strip_default_attrs)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 907, in _export_all_saved_models
    mode=model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.PREDICT)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2188, in _add_meta_graph_for_mode
    check_variables=False))
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 984, in _add_meta_graph_for_mode
    config=self.config)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2192, in _call_model_fn
    return self._call_model_fn_for_inference(features, labels, mode, config)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2253, in _call_model_fn_for_inference
    new_tensors.append(array_ops.identity(t))
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 81, in identity
    return gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3454, in identity
    "Identity", input=input, name=name)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 513, in _apply_op_helper
    raise err
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 510, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1146, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 229, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 208, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/Users/michal/.virtualenvs/deepsat/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 531, in make_tensor_proto
    "supported type." % (type(values), values))
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict_values'> to Tensor. Contents: dict_values([<tf.Tensor 'sat_prob:0' shape=(?,) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'policy_prob:0' shape=(?, ?, 2) dtype=float32>]). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: an answer to this would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Adding argument `export_to_tpu=False` to TPUEstimator constructor prevents the error in Tensorflow 1.12:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(..., export_to_tpu=False)
```

`export_to_tpu=False` disables exporting the TPU version of the model, but CPU version is still exported and this is sufficient to run the model locally. With Tensorflow 1.13 the bug is fixed and the flag is not necessary.

The answer is based on the [Github thread linked in the question](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25652).